# Plus signs being replaced for %252520

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-encoding

When I click on my index'd pages in Google the plus signs in my query string are being replaced (encoded?) for %252520.

Anyone know why?

Example:

```
lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private%252520car%252520park&page=2
```

should be

```
lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private+car+park&page=2
```

I have heard that this is a result of redirecting my urls in htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a space is used in the URI query, it must either be replaced by `%20` ([percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)) or by `+` ([*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) for forms). In your case the data seems to be encoded three times (`%` is encoded with `%25`).

Try these rules to replace such sequences it with `+`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)%(25)+20(.*?%(25)+20.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1+%3 [N]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)%(25)+20(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1+%3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `%25` is the `%` char, `%20` is the space. So it seems your URI was encoded three times

```
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private car park&page=2 =>
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private%20car%20park&page=2 =>
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private%2520car%2520park&page=2 =>
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Private%252520car%252520park&page=2
```

As you can see, a `%` is encoded as `%25`.
So the first time, you get `%20` for the space, then you get a `%25` for the `%` of `%20` followed with the `20`, then, again, same encoding.

There is probably something wrong in the process before the link is provided to Google.